# How to detect controllers while the game is running in PyGame

Tags: python, pygame

Currently, using `pygame.joystick.init()` only works if the controller is on before running the script. I'd like to be able to turn the game on and then turn on the controller while it is running to switch easily between keyboard and joystick.

Comment: try to put pygame.joystick.init() inside the main loop if no joystick have been detected at the start of the game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some reading indicates that pygame 1.# does not seem to be able to deal with joysticks being added or removed while running. That is because pygame is based on SDL, and before version 2, SDL does not handle joysticks being added or removed while running.

SDL vesion 2 apparently does and pygame version 2 is based on SDL 2. You could try upgrading to pygame version 2 and see if that helps.

Comment: After exhausting most other solutions, including putting the joystick function inside event loops, I think this is correct.